# generate swagger json after CDK deployment

Tags: typescript, swagger, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I do `cdk deploy` and I get some of these outputs:

Outputs:
feature.mycomRestApiEndpoint8FB5C89F = https://0lzzz8cdqc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/
feature.mycomRestApiId9C720814 = 0lzzz8cdqc

I would like to automate to have this run, or have it happen within the CDK file:

aws apigateway get-export --parameters extension='integrations' --rest-api-id 0lzzz8cdqc --export-type swagger --accepts application/json --stage-name prod swagger_new.json

Ideally I would love to use `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/CfnDocumentationPart.html` but I am using Typescript and not certain how to generate this.

I am using `RestApi`.

This didn't work:

```
new apigateway.CfnDocumentationPart(this, 'siteDocs', {
  restApiId: api.restApiId,
  location: {
    type: 'RESOURCE',
    method: '*',
    path: '/',
    statusCode: '405'
  },
  properties: `
    {
      "status": "error",
      "code": 405,
      "message": "Method Not Allowed"
    }
  `
});
```

I got this error:

```
[Location type: RESOURCE must have a path and cannot have method, statusCode or
name defined.] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadReq
uestException; Request ID: acfc9f58-534d-4851-a105-7783a4835388; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove lines 5,6 and 7 (method, statusCode and name) as the error message suggests?